# Missing custom attributes and values in SAML repsonse

Tags: community, saml

I am stuck in a odd issue and wanted to see if anyone has faced this earlier or have any suggestions on what can be the reason behind.

Our application has integration with Salesforce where our app is service provider, we use SAML for authentication. In connected apps we have configured certain custom attributes which should be normally sent in response on successful SAML handshake.

On average one out of twenty logins we do not get custom attributes and its values in SAML response - but SAML handshake is successful - we get only standard attributes like userID, email etc.

Comment: Update:  Even though i could not detect the root cause of the issue the fix i did was to re-initiate SAML handshake if i do not get any Custom Attributes in SAML Response, this has worked but the underlying problem still exists but will get masked as Re-initiating SAML is working as expected